# Behaviors of Chow groups under restriction of base field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic 0, and $K$ is a finite extension of $k$. If $X$ is a variety defined over $K$, and by restriction of base field $X$ is also a variety over $k$.

**Question 1**: What are the differences between the subvarieties of $X$ considered as a variety over $K$ and over $k$?

**Question 2**: How does the Chow group $CH^*(X)$ change when we restrict the base field from $K$ to $k$?

Comment: They are the same. A subvariety is a closed immersion $Y\hookrightarrow X$, its $K$ or $k$-scheme structure comes from $X$. This implies in particular that the groups $Z^*(X)$ does not depend on the base field, but only on $X$. (Note that this group is also the free group generated by the points of $X$). For the Chow group, you can see that they does not depends on the base field through restriction using Fulton definition of the rational equivalence : this is the equivalence relation spanned by $[\operatorname{div}(r)]$ where $r$ is in the fraction field of a subvariety.

Comment: @Roland I see, thank you.